# Automapper newbie question regarding list property

Tags: automapper

As a new fan of AutoMapper, how would I use it to do the following:

Given the following classes, I want to create FlattenedGroup from Group where the list of item string maps to the title property of Item.

```
public class Group
{
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Item> Items { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}


public class FlattenedGroup
{
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks

Joseph

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The other thing you can do is create a converter from Item -> string:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Item, string>().ConvertUsing(item => item.Title);
```

Now you don't need to do anything special in your Group -> FlattenedGroup map:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Group, FlattenedGroup>();
```

That's all you'd need there.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try, you can probably use Linq and a lambda expression to map the list of strings in FlattenedGroup with the titles in Group.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Group, FlattenedGroup>()
                .ForMember(f => f.Category, opt => opt.MapFrom(g => g.Category))
                .ForMember(f => f.Items, opt => opt.MapFrom(g => g.Items.Select(d => d.Title).ToList()));
```

*Make sure you add System.Linq to your using statements*